# SQL - Find Differences Between Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have the following table

```
Sku | Number | Name
11    1        hat
12    1        hat
13    1        hats
22    2        car
33    3        truck
44    4        boat
45    4        boat
```

Is there an easy way to figure out how to find the differences within each Number. For example, with the table above, I would want the query to output:

```
13 | 1 | hats
```

The reason for this is because our program processes the rows as long as the number matches the name. If there is an instance where the name doesn't match but the rest of the names do, it will fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the most common value (the "mode") using window functions and aggregation:

```
select t.*
from (select number, name, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by number order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by number, name
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You could then find everything that is not the mode using a `join`.  The easier way is just to change the `where` condition:

```
select t.*
from (select number, name, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by number order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by number, name
     ) t
where seqnum > 1;
```

Note:  If there are ties in frequency for the most common value, then an arbitrary most common value is chosen.

EDIT:

Actually, if you want the original skus, you might as well do the join:

```
with modes as (
      select t.*
      from (select number, name, count(*) as cnt,
                   row_number() over (partition by number order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
            from t
            group by number, name
           ) t
      where seqnum = 1
     )
select t.*
from t join
     modes
     on t.number = modes.number and t.name <> modes.name;
```

This will ignore `NULL` values (but the logic can easily be fixed to accommodate them).